# Use input in python function in from-import statement

Tags: python, function, module, python-import, importerror

I want to use the input (a string) in a function in the file "a.py" to point to another python code file "b.py". In b.py code I have some functions, I want to use.

I have tried:

b.py.

```
def function1(x,y):
    s=x+y
    print(s)
    return

function1(2,4)
```

(b.py is in a subfolder to a.py called .app.dashapp1)

and a.py:

```
def function(func_name):
    name = "app.dashapp1." + func_name
    __import__(name)
    function1(2, 4)
    return

function("b")
```

When I run a.py, I end up getting the error massage:

> "NameError: name 'function1' is not defined"

:(

Would help me out a lot. I've come from matlab/R and am new to Python (love it, though) and this forum.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [advised](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.__import__) to use `importlib.import_module` instead of `__import__`:

---

`a.py`:

```py
import importlib

def func(name):
        module_str = "dashapp1." + name  # get module str
        module = importlib.import_module(module_str)  # import module from str
        f = getattr(module, "function")  # get function "function" in module
        f(1, 2)  # execute function "function" in module

func("b")
```

`dashapp1/b.py`:

```py
def function(a, b):
        print("{a} - {b}".format(a=a, b=b))
```

**Output:**

```
$ python3.7 a.py 
1 - 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to bind the name `function1` to the function.

```
def function(func_name):
    name = "app.dashapp1." + func_name
    function1 = __import__(name).function1
    function1(2, 4)
    return

function("a")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the fast answer! I get this error now, using the proposed code:

> AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'function1'

Comment: function assumes that a module app.dashapp1.<funcname> has a function1, if you instead want to use the module b you should replace `name = "app.dashapp1." + func_name` with `name = "b"`